# How To Pivot table using SQL server

Tags: sql-server

i creating SQL table  its  have three column fields

```
   NAME       TYPE             Amount
    RAJ      401K %            500
    Kumar    ROTH              600
    RAJ      401K %            500
    Kumar    ROTH              700
    Karthi   401K %            1500
    RAj      Roth              800
    Tony     DPD                8
```

above table i have three column Fields Name and Type finally Amount. i try  convert this table like  separate columns Type. in my table Raj come in table many time  so i want  to sum Raj all value which  values come with 401K table finally its show single value. its  added 401k value. Roth value seperate like this

```
 Name          401k%    Roth     Amount
 Raj           1000     800      1800
 Kumar          0       1300     1300  
 Karthi        1500      0       1500. 
 Nimi           0        0         0        -- this is should Remove only value come  with only 401k% and Roth . other value should be delete .
```

i want like this. i am trying to achive this using Pivot talbe i am getting Null value

```
select [Name],[401k%] ,[Roth%]
 from DeductionHistory
 PIVOT
 ( SUM(Amount) FOR DeductionName IN([401k%],[Roth%])
  )
AS Pivottable
```

please any one help me . how to get value Like this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE #TABLE111
    ([NAME] VARCHAR(6), [TYPE] VARCHAR(6), [AMOUNT] INT)

INSERT INTO #TABLE111
    ([NAME], [TYPE], [AMOUNT])
VALUES
    ('RAJ', '401K %', 500),
    ('KUMAR', 'ROTH', 600),
    ('RAJ', '401K %', 500),
    ('KUMAR', 'ROTH', 700),
    ('KARTHI', '401K %', 1500),
    ('RAJ', 'ROTH', 800)

SELECT NAME ,ISNULL([401K %],0) [401K %] ,ISNULL([ROTH],0)  [ROTH] ,ISNULL([401K %],0)+ISNULL([ROTH],0) 'TOTAL'
FROM 
(
  SELECT *
  FROM #TABLE111
) SRC
PIVOT
(
  SUM([AMOUNT])
  FOR [TYPE] IN ([401K %], [ROTH] )
) PIV
ORDER BY NAME DESC
```

output

```
NAME    401K %  ROTH    TOTAL
RAJ    1000     800      1800
Kumar   0       1300     1300
Karthi  1500    0        1500
```

Comment: thank you Chankya.u Helpmed today lot.one more Question  how to Remove if suppose  401k  and Roth  both value 0 . how to remove Zero value when Both Column comes Zero

Answer (score 0):

```
--I have included DPD the query
DECLARE @DeductionHistory TABLE (NAME VARCHAR(20), [TYPE] VARCHAR(20),Amount MONEY)
INSERT INTO @DeductionHistory VALUES
    ('RAJ','401K%',500),
    ('Kumar','ROTH',600),
    ('RAJ','401K%',500),
    ('Kumar','ROTH',700),
    ('Karthi','401K%',1500),
    ('RAj','ROTH',800),
     ('Tony'   ,'DPD', 8)


 /*****Use a VTE or temp table*****/


 ;WITH DeductionHistory
 AS(
 SELECT * FROM @DeductionHistory 
 PIVOT
 (
 SUM(Amount) FOR [TYPE] IN ([401K%],[ROTH],[DPD])
 ) PV1
)
SELECT
[NAME]  
,ISNULL([401K%],0) AS [401K%]   
,ISNULL([ROTH],0) AS [ROTH]
,ISNULL([DPD],0) AS [DPD]
,ISNULL([401K%],0)+ISNULL([ROTH],0)+ISNULL([DPD],0) AS Amount
FROM DeductionHistory
```

OUTPUT

```
   NAME    401K%       ROTH    DPD    Amount
    Karthi  1500.00    0.00     0.00  1500.00
    Kumar   0.00       1300.00  0.00  1300.00
    RAJ     1000.00    800.00   0.00  1800.00
    Tony    0.00       0.00     8.00  8.00
```

Comment: i want  to Remove   who has Zero 401k% and  Roth. this table import from Excel sheet, i want to select who has value 401k% and Roth other value i want Remove

Comment: if you want to remove any thing exclude them in where clause eg

Comment: if you want to remove any thing exclude them in where clause eg WHER [401K%] <>0

Comment: i will try  it sir